# Automatic answer (input) in PuTTY

Tags: ssh, putty

Is there any way to provide answers (input) to commands executed in PuTTY?
Lets say I have a PuTTY session named TEST and I want to start the session with some commands stored in `putty.cmd` file. After triggering some functions it expects an option to select, so how can I automate the response

Ex: When I trigger `phone` command it gives option like

1. Initiate a call
2. Send SMS
3. Quit

I have to select an option.

`putty.cmd` has just one line

```
./phone
echo 2 (this didn't enable option 2)
```

Is there any way to select that option?

Answer (score 0):

For automation, use [Plink](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html) (from PuTTY package). It's a console equivalent of PuTTY. So it supports input redirection:

```
( 
  echo ./phone
  echo 2
) | plink username@example.com
```

---

Though the correct option would be to find out, if the command (`phone`) accepts some arguments/switches to select the options you want to use.